# delete records in one table based on multiple column values in second table

Tags: db2

I need to insert and delete records in table 1 based on the data in multiple columns in table 2.

Example:  Table1 and Table2 have identical columns: address, city, state, and zip.

Table1 is the master table with millions and millions of records. 
Table2 (thousands of records) is a table based on data that changed in some way - although it may not be a change in data in this table.

Matching records means that the address, city, state, and zip are identical in value in both tables.

So I want to do 2 operations:

- Insert records into Table1 that only exist in Table2
- Delete records from Table1 where the record is not in Table2 but the city 
  is in Table2

Based on the size of Table1, I need a very efficient way to execute this.
I know some SQL - but not to the level this would require if done with SQL.

This is a DB2 database - version 10.5.

Answer (score 5):

- Operation 1

  Insert records into `Table1` that only exist in `Table2`:

  ```
  INSERT INTO Table1
      (address, city, state, zip)
  SELECT address, city, state, zip  FROM Table2
  EXCEPT
  SELECT address, city, state, zip  FROM Table1 ;
  ```
- Operation 2

  Delete records from `Table1` where the record is not in `Table2` but the `city` is in `Table2`.

  (assuming that the columns ar enot nullable. If they allow nulls, it would be better to rewrite the `NOT IN` with a `NOT EXISTS` subquery):

  ```
  DELETE FROM Table1 
  WHERE (address, city, state, zip)
         NOT IN
        (SELECT address, city, state, zip  FROM Table2)
    AND city IN
        (SELECT city FROM Table2) ;
  ```

As for performance and efficiency, I have almost zero experience with DB2, so it would be better if you waited for some other answer. But an index on all the columns `(address, city, state, zip)` - on both tables - would probably be the best you can do for the queries, plus a single index on `(city)`. Or perhaps combine the two suggestions in one index with all the 4 columns but choose `city` for the 1st part of the index: `(city, address, state, zip)`.

You haven't provided the tables' structure but the 4 columns seem appropriate for a `UNIQUE` constraint so you may already have such an index.

Comment: Thanks so much. I actually have a table with multiple other columns and the columns are all different than the example I gave - but the example described the problem easily and your solution should do the trick. Thanks again

Comment: @Chris: I'm afraid that syntax is Postgres specific, but DB2 does have a similar means of selecting from DML statements which could be used here (see [data change table reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-6-1-1-0&lang=en)) (`BEGIN` is also a pg-ism). On the subject of performance I generally found DB2 to be happier with `EXCEPT` than `NOT IN` but ymmv.